# How do I retrieve value under aria-hidden

Tags: python, html, selenium, mozilla

im trying to extract a true/false value which is in a  tag (Mozilla Firefox). However, I cant seem to get it. I am using Selenium on Python.

I have tried to get element using two different methods:

```
output = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tr/td[1]/span/span').get_text()
```

and

```
output = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="prefs"]/tr/td[1]/span/span').get_text()
```

but it only returns `Unable to locate element: /html/body/table/tr/td[1]/span/span`

[This is the HTML code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHIFf.jpg)

How can I retrieve the value? I've been scratching my head for the past few hours. TIA

Comment: #Update, I managed to solve it by adding a minimum of 1 seconds sleep. I dont understand why, but it somehow works. The method suggested by @Arundeep Chohan works, but only when i add a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="prefs"]/tr/td[1]/span/span').text
```

If you want the text false use .text if you want the aria-hidden use .get_attribute('aria-hidden')

Switch to using By since the other method is depreciated.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```